# Proving isomorphism between circle group $U(\mathbb{C})$ and $G_m(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, complex-numbers, algebraic-groups

I have some problems solving the following problem from my textbook:

---

Let $G_m(B)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{A}^2(B)=B^2|xy=1\}$ where we define multiplication componentwise $(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)=(x_1x_2,y_1y_2)$. Now, consider also the Cirlce group $U=U(1)$, defined by $U(B)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{A}^2(B)=B^2|x^2+y^2=1\}$. Here, multiplication is given by $(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2)=(x_1x_2-y_1y_2,x_1y_2+x_2y_1)$.

**(a)** Show that $U(\mathbb{R})\not\cong G_m(\mathbb{R})$

**(b)** Show that $\varphi:(x,y)\mapsto (x+iy,\frac{1}{x+iy})$ is an isomorphism from $U(\mathbb{C})$ to $G_m(\mathbb{C})$.

---

**Solution:**

**(a)** $U(\mathbb{R}$) has an element of order $4$, namely $(0,1)$, but on the otherhand $G_m(\mathbb{R})\cong\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ has no element of order $4$. Hence, they cannot be isomorphic.

**(b)** I think the homomorphism part is easy, it is just a matter of checking the definition. But I don't manage to prove it is bijective. They even gave me how to do it in the exercise but I still don't manage to do it. The hint they are giving is that I should construct an inverse. To do this I start with $(z,\frac{1}{z})\in G_m(\mathbb{C})$. I want $z=x+iy$ and $x^2+y^2=1$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$. I should use substitution to solve for one of $x,y$ purely in terms of $z$ and then substitute back to get the other among $x,y$ in terms of $z$.

This is how I did it:
$$z=x+iy\iff x=z-iy.$$
Substituting this expression into $x^2+y^2=1$ gives me
$$(z-iy)^2+y^2=z^2-2izy-y^2+y^2=z^2-2izy=z(z-2iy)=1\iff$$
$$z-2iy=\frac{1}{z}\iff z-\frac{1}{z}=2iy\iff y=\frac{1}{2i}(z-\frac{1}{z}).$$
Then I substitute it back to get
$x=z-\frac{1}{2}(z-\frac{1}{z})$. I don't know what to do now. I think this is a wrong interpretation of how I should do it. I would be really happy if someone could help me out. Thanks! :)

Comment: The components $x, y$ are just the real and imaginary parts of $x + iy$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're done.  You've found that if $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is invertible and $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$, then $z=x+iy$ and $x^2+y^2=1$ are both true iff $y=\frac{1}{2i}(z-1/z)$ and $x=z-\frac{1}{2}(z-1/z)$.  That is, $(x,y)\in U(\mathbb{C})$ and $(z,1/z)=\varphi(x,y)$ iff $x$ and $y$ are given by those formulas.  This proves that $\varphi$ is a bijection (for any $(z,1/z)\in \mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{C})$, there is a unique $(x,y)$ such that $(z,1/z)=\varphi(x,y)$).